A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask
I have been trying to implement a mobile application which was supposed to use Dagger Hilt, Glide and Kapt. However, when I tried to implement it, i got this error
error message:

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)


i tried to change hilt version to latest version but still i face the same issues
build.gradle (project)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.51.1' apply false


    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
//    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.8' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

setting.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'   // aar
        }
    }
}


dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'   // aar
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    }
}

build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.print.app'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.print.app"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

  

    def setOutputFileName = { prefix ->
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${prefix}-${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}-${variant.mergedFlavor.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", LIVE_URL
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            
        }

        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", DEVELOPMENT_URL
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }


    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
        buildConfig  true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
        }
    }

    
}

 

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation project(path: ':network')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.51.1"

    //Preferences DataStore
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.0")

    // Lifecycle
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
     implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'

    //ssp and sdp lib
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

    //coroutines lib
    def coroutines = "1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines"

//    //glide lib
//    def glide = "4.16.0"
//    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide"
//    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide"

    // Using Exoplayer lib so we can manage cache easily.
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.7"

//    //Firebase dependencies
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
//    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx"
//    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")


    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'

//    kapt 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.6.2'
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.6.2"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}


terminal message error


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
Required by:
project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.2
project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.1.2
> No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
- Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
- Other compatible attribute:
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
- Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
- Other compatible attributes:
- Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
- Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
- Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')



Update: i set java version to 17 and jdk also to 17 . and still same error


Please paste the error message as text, not as a screenshot.

@Leviathan i did please check it ,

The first part of the error stacktrace could be useful. Run your Gradle command with flag -s to get one (or Android Studio should offer the option to re-run with --stacktrace option when it fails)

@SimonJacobs i attached the terminal error message above

The error message tells you you need be running the build on Java 11 or later to use this version of the Android plugin.
Make sure you have such a version of the JDK installed, and point Android Studio towards it (this question has details), or set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to its location if you are running Gradle from the command line.

i used java 17 and also tried 11 but still same error . also i update it to oracle jdk 22.0.1

You need to be sure you have the correct JDK set. It can be non-trivial. See eg this question. Run java --version in your terminal to confirm

when i run the same command i got 17 it is correct . i updated the jdk in android studio to 17 also but still i got the same error

1. You need to change which JDK Gradle used for running. From JDK 8 to JDK 11.

Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8.

As the error message suggests.
Check this image for more information.


2. Also this
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

to
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

or via IDE like this 

JDK used is 17 . why is saying it is 8 ?

Can you open preferences > Build > Gradle > JDK version and share what version you are using ?

i update it to oracle jdk 22.0.1

you need to use open idk 11

@m.karman Did it got resolved ? Also you need to export path of jdk 11

not yet . the java jdk used on my device is 17 now . i updated JDK Gradle in android studio to the same 17 . i still got the same error , is it necessary to use only 11  ?

does it working with 11 ?
